# Basis elements for $Q(t)$ as a $Q(t^2)$-vector space.

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$ be the fields of rational functions with $t$ and $t^2$ as indeterminates. Both of these fields are infinite-dimensional. How can I determine the dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ as a $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$-vector space? The answer is in fact 2 when I thought it would still be infinity, but I didn't have a proper justification for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: The polynomial $X^2-t^2\in \mathbb{Q}(t^2)[X]$ has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, but no root in $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

First, forget that there's anything "infinite-dimensional" about these two fields. A *field* can't be infinite-dimensional, rather, they're only infinite-dimensional as vector spaces over $\mathbb{Q}$, and that structure isn't coming in to this question at all. So you just need to find a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ over $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$ and see how many elements it has. I claim $\{1,t\}$ is a basis: $1$ and $t$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$ because $1/t$ isn't an element of $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$. On the other hand, they span. To see this, consider that $\mathbb{Q}(t)/\mathbb{Q}(t^2)t=\mathbb{Q}(t^2),$ which is a 1-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}(t^2)$-vector space spanned by 1.

Comment: The hint gave me what I was missing, but I also benefited from your answer. Thank you, Kevin.

Comment: Then @algkid you should upvote this answer as it is helpful. You can upvote as many answers as you like, and then you *accept* the one (besides the upvoting) which you find **the most** helpful of them all, as you did with egreg's answer. +1